# How to select some elements as selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements like `TextBox`, `Select`. I have a script to hide some elements. For this I use the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).on('change', '#TypeId', function (e) {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  if (selected == 1) {
    $($('#Issue').parent(), $('#ServiceRequestId').parent()).hide();
    console.log('test');
  }
});
```

It just hides the first selector. When I change the selector like below it works fine:

```
$( $('#ServiceRequestId').parent()).hide();
```

Comment: Paste your html code too.

Comment: ok , let me to upload

Comment: Since `parent()` returns the parent of each element inside the JQuery object, you could first combine the 2 elements (in one selector using `,` ) as:  `$('#Issue, #ServiceRequestId').parent().hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [second argument is the context](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) in jQuery which would help to filter element within that context.

I think you want to combine both objects, for that use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method to combine two independent jQuery objects.

```
$('#Issue').parent().add($('#ServiceRequestId').parent()).hide();
```

---

Or provide both [jQuery objects within an array](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray).

```
$([$('#Issue').parent(), $('#ServiceRequestId').parent()]).hide()
```

Comment: @KarInter :  glad to help :)